# jQuery: Hovering over an element brings fades in another element, but when hovering over that element it disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class called .description that shows up when ever the mouse is hovered over a class called .image 
HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <a href="?page=page1>"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="80" height="80"></a>
</div>
<div class="description" style="display: none;"> description 1 </div>

<div class="image">
    <a href="?page=page2>"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="80" height="80"></a>
</div>
<div class="description" style="display: none;"> description 2 </div>

<div class="image">
    <a href="?page=page3"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="80" height="80"></a>
</div>
<div class="description" style="display: none;"> description 3 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
    $(this).next(".description").fadeToggle();
});
```

A working version of this was provided by another user, and I have slightly modified it and put it up here: http://jsfiddle.net/zakiaziz/qnWpy/2/

When ever I hover over the .image class the .description class shows up fine. The problem I am having is that when ever the mouse is hovering over where the description class should show up the description class does show up and then disappear. Some times it blinks erratically.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass only one function to jQuery.hover, it calls it on `hover` **and** on `out`.

To cancel any action on mouse out, provide an empty handler.

```
        $(".image").hover(function() {
            $(this).next(".description").fadeToggle();
        }, function() {});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qnWpy/4/

Comment: I need the box that pops up to go away after the mouse leaves the image

Comment: The link you posted does just that.